# ios next and previous buttons

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a next button that I want to disappear when I get to the last result of an array and I want my previous button to disappear when I am at the first result of the array. I have figured out how to make them disappear when only one result is found.

Contacts is the array.

next Button:

```
        //button look
if (contacts != nil) { 
    if ([contacts count] > 1 ) [self.view addSubview:nextButton];
```

Previous button:

```
       //button look
if (contacts != nil) { 
    if ([contacts count] > 1 ) [self.view addSubview:previousButton];
```

I have tried this

```
if ([contacts count] < (index-1)) [self.view addSubview:nextButton];
```

I get this error "Ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('NSUInterger'(aka 'unsigned int') and 'char * (*)(const char *,int)')" The button is there it just doesn't disappear when it gets to the last result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nil just tells it there are no more elements to be included in the array. U can't use to check... try objectAtIndex:0 and objectAtIndex:[contacts count] - 1.

Comment: I don't understan what is it you are trying to do. Are you trying to hide `nextButton` if `[contacts count] < (index-1)`?

Comment: It would display if contacts count < index -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like index is a `NSUInterger`. count is a int and NSUInteger is typedef to unsigned integer. try changing index where ever your setting it to a int or typecasting it to a int where your using it for comparison.

For the part about the button, if your logic is right and you are trying to remove "nextButton" from view  you can either hide or remove it from the view like so:

```
// To remove button
if ([contacts count] < (index-1)) [nextButton removeFromSuperview];
```

or

```
//To hide button
if ([contacts count] < (index-1)) nextButton.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Changed index to int and the error is gone. now it just wont make the buttons do what their supposed to do.

Comment: that works. thanks a lot! I changed it a little though
    if ([contacts count] < index-1)){ nextButton.hidden= NO;
    }else{ nextButton.hidden = YES;
    }

Comment: great, also note you can call contacts.count in the if statements

Answer (score 0):

You never remove it from the superView, so it will never go away. You should use the hidden property of the button i.e.

```
[nextButton setHidden:NO];
```

or YES if you want to hide it.

The error is probably from the index entity, did you typecast that as a NSUInterger? change that to a uint or an int. (just posted a bit late, but this has been mentioned in other answer :D)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([contacts objectAtIndex:[contacts count]-1])
 { 
    [self.view addSubview:nextButton];
}
if([contacts objectAtIndex:0)
{
 [self.view addSubview:previousButton];
}
```

Hope this helps...nil just tells it there are no more elements to be included in the array. U can't use it to check..